# Operators && and || are objects in ruby?

Tags: ruby

In the tutorial  [Rubymonk](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1/chapters/6-objects/lessons/35-introduction-to-objects) says :

"In Ruby, just like in real life, our world is filled with objects. Everything is an object - integers, characters, text, arrays - everything."

But && and || are operators, operators are objects too ? how check ?

this is not going against the philosophy of ruby "All is a object" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you define "everything". I personally would never claim that each individual concept in ruby is an object. I suppose there isn't really a good definition to describe how ruby works. I think you just have to accept the way ruby does it, which will become plain as you use it.

If you want to see if something is an object, try assigning it to a variable, or calling a method on it. You'll get an error if you try to do that with an operator. A notable exception is methods, which aren't objects but return objects.

Note that the concept of an object is somewhat abstract. Two variables can point to the same object. Every object is represented by an `object_id`. You might think of an object_id like a location in memory. Or, you can think of an object as a house, and multiple address books can contain the house's address.

```
# point 2 variables to the same object
>> s = t = 's'
=> "s"
>> s.object_id
=> 70269794388360
>> t.object_id
=> 70269794388360

# get the object by id (for demonstration only; I don't recommend using this in application code)
>> ObjectSpace._id2ref(70269794388360)
=> "s"

# modifying the object. both variables "see" the change
>> s << '_'
=> "s_"
>> t
=> "s_"
```

Continuing the house analogy, appending to a string via `<<` is like bringing a new chair into the house. Everyone who follows their address book to that house (using the address) will see that the house (object) has the new chair.

The ruby language designers did not see a reason to allow treating operators like `&&` as objects. Can you see any reason to allow it?

Answer (score 4):

#### The `&&` and `||` Tokens are Operators

The `&&` and `||` tokens are not objects, they are operators defined by Ruby's parser. You can dig through the source code to find the actual definitions and implementation details, if you're interested. To get you started, here's a regular expression match to get you started in reviewing the source:

```
$ fgrep -n '%token tANDOP tOROP' ruby-1.9.3-p194/ext/ripper/ripper.y
719:%token tANDOP tOROP /* && and || */
```

Comment: ok, are tokens like 'if','else', etc. why '==' (for example) is a method and '||' is a operator, why this difference ?

Comment: perhaps because it can make sense to define == differently for different classes, but you can't define || and && differently for different classes, because they are to do with truthiness, which is the same for all objects (false and nil are falsy, everything else is truthy)

Answer (score 1):

Operators are not objects, most operators in Ruby are methods.

You can check it by running `irb` and looking at `public_methods` of some object:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> "a"=="b"
=> false
irb(main):002:0> "a".public_methods
=> [:<=>, :==,.........
```

And what about operators from the question, `&&` and `||` is hardcoded into Ruby language, but `==` is mixed in from `Comparable` module.

Comment: '==' are method of class [BasicObject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-3D-3D) , but '||' or '&&' no have class, and public_methods output dont exist

Comment: Not all operators are methods. Some operators are just parser tokens.

Comment: Why? this is not going against the philosophy of ruby "All is a object" ?

Comment: The answer edited, hope it correct now. `&&` is hardcoded, because it is serves execution flow, like `if` ... `end`

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, all variable types refer to objects (like Python). But operators are not objects. You can check by trying to call the to_s() method on them.

Comment: how would you call `to_s()` with `||` as argument? What?

Comment: I meant calling `||.to_s()` which doesn't work, proving that `||` is not an object. The OP asked how to check.

Comment: Are you saying that actually runs in ruby? :D

Comment: No, I'm saying that it doesn't work! It _would_ work if `||` were an object, though.

Comment: So in Ruby, Everything not is an object because exists operators, right ?

Comment: No, Andres. In ruby, there exist objects (all the variable types), operators, control keywords, and some other things. Don't take that tutorial's "all things" too literally, it should have been written "all variables".

Comment: It's a bit misleading to say that a variable is an object, since multiple variables can (and often do) point to the same object.

Comment: Thanks, Kelvin, I reworded it. Hows that now?

Answer (score 0):

Most Operator in ruby are actually method calls.

```
2.+(3)  # 5
```

Here's a good explanation : http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/ruby-for-newbies-operators-and-their-methods/

Comment: *Some* operators are methods. The OP is specifically asking about the `&&` and `||` operators, though, which are not methods.

Comment: But you cant do true.||false or some like that , why?

Comment: @AndrésRicardoTorresMartínez No, you can't. `true.||false` triggers a "SyntaxError: unexpected tOROP" error.